# Difference between \r and \n

Tags: javascript, regex

What is the difference between `\r` and `\n` in a regular expression?

Can someone explain it with an example?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

`\r` is "Carriage Return" (CR, ASCII character 13), `\n` is "Line Feed" (LF, ASCII character 10). Back in the days, you had two ASCII characters at the end of each line to tell a printer what to do - CR would tell the printer to go back to the left edge of the paper, LF would advance to the next line.

Operating systems still have different conventions as to what the end of a line looks like -- some of them have `\n\r`, some have `\n`, some have `\r\n`.

In Javascript, you mostly deal with `\n` - this is how strings are typically switching to the next line. However, depending on what strings you are working with, you may be encountering `\r` as well.

Comment: I don't know of any platform or protocol that specifies `\n\r` as the new line function; the native line separator on MAC OS prior to OS X was `\r` alone.

Comment: @Alan If you want us to tell you, just ask. :)

Comment: @bzim: You mean you know of a system that uses `\n\r` (`LFCR`, `0x0A 0x0D`) as a line separator?  Do tell!

Comment: This answer has been added to the [Stack Overflow Regular Expression FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496), under "Escape Sequences".

Comment: When would you use one over the other?

Answer (score 26):

Normally `\r` represents a carriage return character (ASCII `0x0d`), and `\n` is a newline character (ASCII `0x0a`).  [This page](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev2.shtml) has a list of all the special characters, quoted here for completeness:

> - `\f` matches form-feed.
> - `\r` matches carriage return.
> - `\n` matches linefeed.
> - `\t` matches horizontal tab.
> - `\v` matches vertical tab.
> - `\0` matches `NUL` character.
> - `[\b]` matches backspace.
> - `\s` matches whitespace (short for `[\f\n\r\t\v\u00A0\u2028\u2029]`).
> - `\S` matches anything but a whitespace (short for
>   `[^\f\n\r\t\v\u00A0\u2028\u2029]`).
> - `\w` matches any alphanumerical character (word characters) including
>   underscore (short for `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`).
> - `\W` matches any non-word characters (short for `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`).
> - `\d` matches any digit (short for `[0-9]`).
> - `\D` matches any non-digit (short for `[^0-9]`).
> - `\b` matches a word boundary (the position between a word and a space).
> - `\B` matches a non-word boundary (short for `[^\b]`).
> - `\cX` matches a control character. E.g: `\cm` matches `control-M`.
> - `\xhh` matches the character with two characters of hexadecimal code `hh`.
> - `\uhhhh` matches the Unicode character with four characters of
>   hexadecimal code `hhhh`.

Comment: Think of an old manual type writer ... carriage return moves the current 'position' back to the start of the line.

Comment: @Avinash, @nonnb is correct - carriage return and line feed are terms back from the days of paper terminals; the carriage return character moves the printing head back to column zero, and line feed advances the paper roll by one line.

Comment: `\0` doesn't belong there. `\{number}` is just an octal escape sequence.

Answer (score 9):

`\n` is linefeed

`\r` is carriage return

In windows, for example, line endings are `\r\n`. In the vast majority of other operating systems, they are `\n`.

Comment: Not entirely true. OS 9 for example had \r\n, IIRC.

Comment: And one Mac OS once upon a time used just `\r`, IIRC.

Answer (score 7):

`\r` and `\n` are digital representations of the way you would advance to the next line on a typewriter. `\r` is a [carriage return](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) and `\n` is a [newline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) (also known as a linefeed). On a typewriter, to go to the start of the new line, you would **return** the carriage to the leftmost position and then **feed** the paper up a line.

Unix uses `\n` to mean new line, Macs prior to OS9 used `\r`, and Windows uses `\r\n`.

Answer (score 3):

`\n` --> For a new line

`\r` --> For carriage return