# Trying to ascertain the Regex to remove newline from start and end of content in <PRE> tag, using Regex.Replace from .NET

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a "pre" which is getting newlines added before the content and after the content ie:

```
<pre>

My Content
</pre>
```

The above seems to be equivalent to 2 newlines before and 1 after.

I would like to parse my HTML string for all "pre" tags and to remove these before and after newlines.

I would use ASP.NET code to do the replacing:

```
Regex.replace(myHtmlString,@"Regex Pattern",String.Empty);
```

The result should be:

```
<pre>My Content</pre>
```

So what would the "Regex Pattern" look like please?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT

Answer so far:

```
strCleanXhtmlDoc = Regex.Replace(strCleanXhtmlDoc,@"<pre>[\r\n]*(.*?)[\r\n]*</pre>", "<pre>$1</pre>")
```

The replace bit is $1.

EDIT:

Strruggling to get the Regex to work with:

```
<pre style="color: #a11f98;font-family: calibri;font-size: 14pt;font-style: normal;font-weight: normal;">

L1

L11

L111
</pre>
```

Which does need matching, to produce:

```
<pre style="color: #a11f98;font-family: calibri;font-size: 14pt;font-style: normal;font-weight: normal;">L1

L11

L111</pre>
```

Comment: Take a look at the [Stack Overflow Regular Expression FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496) under "Escape Sequences", particularly at [`\n` and `\r`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3451192), and then give it a try in one of the listed online regex testers (in the bottom section).

Comment: I don't recommend it, but [here's a spoiler](http://regex101.com/r/fX8fE2) to @aliteralmind's post if you can't figure it out.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for this. How would you tweak this to search for <pre> contains /r/n. I have come across : <PRE\b[^>]*>(.*?)</PRE> . Sorry I am very new to regex.

Comment: @aliteralmind, thanks your for your comment. I have looked at the FAQ.

Comment: Search for `<pre>[\r\n]*(.*?)[\r\n]*</pre>`, replace with `<pre>\1</pre>`

Comment: @CAustin, Thanks for your comment. Very helpful. Forgive my ignorance, but what does \1 in <pre>\1</pre> mean? I did try this in a tester and got <pre>\1</pre> as the answer and not <pre>My Content</pre>

Comment: Depending on the type of regex engine your tester is using, you may have to use `$1` instead.  Anyway, `\1` (and `\2`, `\3`, etc) are references to capturing groups in the regex pattern.  Anything matched within the first set of `()` can later be referenced by `\1`, either in the replacement, or later in the pattern itself.  See this for a more complete explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21880127/have-trouble-understanding-capturing-groups-and-back-references

Comment: @CAustin, OK thank for this . Learning a bit more. I am not totally sure what my Regest.Replace state might look like. I have added it as an edit. The key question is how to get the \1 bit working, and this might be a .NET question.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice you were using .NET.  In that case, yes, you'll need to use `$1` for the reference.

Comment: You need to use Multi-line regex http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs

Comment: Still having problems with the testing. I have added a tag that does also need to be matched. I could not get it to work in the tester. Possibly need tweaking?? Thanks to all. See 2nd EDIT

Comment: This `(<pre[^>]*>)\s*([^<]*?)\s*(</pre>)` with the replacement `$1$2$3` will work as long as you don't have sub tags.

Comment: and this works even with sub tags `(<pre[^>]*>)\s*([\w\W]*?)\s*(</pre>)`. replacement is `$1$2$3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex you need is this `(<pre[^>]*>)\s*([\w\W]*?)\s*(</pre>)`

To break it down

- `(<pre[^>]*>)` matches the start pre tag including any attributes. `[^>]*` this bit does most of the work and means all chars that aren't `>`
- `\s*` then we match all the whitespace we can
- `([\w\W]*?)` this grabs the content `\w\W` means any character and is more inclusive than `.`. The `?` is present so that this doesnt also grab the whitespace that the next bit is meant to grab its a non greedy modifier.
- `\s*` match the whitespace at the end of the content before the end tag
- `(</pre>)` match the end tag nothing special here

The replacement is `$1$2$3` to grab the 3 parenthesized sections and put them back together without the whitespace.

Hope that makes some sense and helps you write your next one.

Comment: This was a very helpful reply, and wonderful explanation which certainly assists with my journey of learning Regex. So a big thank you. It all works wonderfully. Thank you for enlightening me on this multiple replacement mechanism. Also I feel a number of folks have helped me, so a big thank you. I have tried to so my appreciation by marking up the comments.

Comment: One last question on this. Some folks have "do not recommend this approach". I am curious to know why. It seems pretty powerful to me. Perhaps its is very CPU intensive and knocks application significantly, not that I have noticed. Some folks have suggested that one should use HtmlAgility Pack as a better solution???

Comment: Regex is notoriously bad at parsing things like html anything more complicated than this and it all starts becoming really hard (for instance if you had a pre inside a pre this stops working and the regex becomes way longer). If your intent is to be parsing a lot of html then using something like the HtmlAgility Pack would end up a lot easier.