# JavaScript string won't match, even if it is matching

Tags: javascript

So I have a short question: I'm reading data from a file, that works. I'm adding these data to a string, that's ok.

But when it comes to comparing these data on an if-statement it doesn't simply become true.

I've done `console.log` of the string, and it appears correct:

```
["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
```

I've tried to rewrite the data, I've checked for syntax errors on the text file, but everything looks correct.

```
for (var i = 0; i < lineArray.length; i++) {
        var singleLine= lineArray[i].split(' ');
        console.log(singleLine) //And I get the array ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
          if (singleLine[4] === 'E') {
             console.log("it works")
   }
}
```

The thing I'm expecting to happen is to get the 'it works' on the console.

Comment: There must be something else there in `singleLine[4]`. Have you tried adding `console.log(singleLine[4].length)`?

Comment: Since you are reading from a file - could it be the encoding thats causing the inequality?

Comment: Add what object you are getting as singleLine, not console log but actual object

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, you should use let/const rather than var if you can.

Comment: What is `lineArray` and `lineArr`? Please provide input examples.

Comment: You can console.log(singleLine[4], 'E') to see if there's a difference

Comment: @Pointy sorry for late reply! The length of the elements are always +1 for the last element on the line. For example the length of the 'E' is 2.

Comment: @MZ97 well that means there's some additional character in the string. You can use `.charCodeAt()` to check the Unicode numeric value for each part of the string.

Comment: @BroBan I think every last element on every line is having a kind of new-line (\n), but that is invisible. I have tried to compare it with 'E\n' or 'E \n'. But no success

Comment: @Pointy I get that the second char is 13. Any idea what that is?

Comment: That's a "carriage return" character, picked up from the original file probably.

Comment: @Pointy Thank you so much for your help! The solution was to compare it with 'E\r'. I'll soon be answering the question on my own here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem on this case was the invisible ['Carriage Return'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451147/difference-between-r-and-n/3451192#3451192) or `'\r'` on every last element of every line.

The solution on my case was to compare the letter `E` with `'E\r'`. This will result on the if-statement to be true.

Answer (score 0):

```
let lineArray = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"];

lineArray.forEach(a => {
        console.log(a); 
    if (a ==="E") console.log("its work")
    })
```